# How to include those files which internally include other files?

Tags: php

This is my file structure

```php
\+-- config
|   +-- config1.php
|   +-- config2.php
\+-- test
|   +-- test1
|      +-- innerRunner.php
\+-- outerRunner.php
```

this is `config1.php`

```php
<?php
require_once 'config/config2.php';
```

this is `config2.php`

```php
<?php
function runConfig2(){
    echo "control in config2";
}
runConfig2();
```

this is `innerRunner.php`

```php
<?php
require_once("../../config/config1.php");
```

this is `outerRunner.php`

```php
<?php
require_once("config/config1.php");
```

When i exceute outerRunner.php then everything works fine but when i run innerRunner.php
it shows error

```
Warning: require_once(config/config2.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/config/config1.php on line 2

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'config/config2.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /var/www/config/config1.php:2 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/test/test1/innerRunner.php(2): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/config/config1.php on line 2
```

Can anyone help me with this? 
Here is the link of sandbox for the same:
[Link](https://phpsandbox.io/n/crimson-scene-r00k-qtosz?files=%2Fconfig%2Fconfig2.php)

PS : I can't make any changes in config1 or config2, i need to do something with innerRunner.php only.

Answer (score 0):

in file config `config1.php` remove directory `config`

```php
<?php

require_once './config2.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in `innerRunner.php`

```
<?php
#change the current working dir 
chdir('/var/www');
require_once("config/config1.php");
#change it back to the current dir
chdir(__DIR__);
```

But this is really a bad approach to do something like this.

Normaly you should only do `require_once 'config2.php';` `(config1.php)` in the first place.

There is no real reason to do `require_once 'config/config2.php';` there.